# Anchor Installation Fails

Tags: anchor, installation

I'm trying to install anchor on Ubuntu 22.04 but the installation fails. Here's the terminal output:

```
 cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor avm --locked --force

    Updating git repository `https://github.com/project-serum/anchor`
  Installing avm v0.25.0 (https://github.com/project-serum/anchor#93332766)
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling libc v0.2.119
   Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.36
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.2
   Compiling syn v1.0.86
   Compiling memchr v2.4.1
   Compiling log v0.4.14
   Compiling pin-project-lite v0.2.8
   Compiling cc v1.0.73
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.24
   Compiling bytes v1.1.0
   Compiling futures-core v0.3.21
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling itoa v1.0.1
   Compiling futures-task v0.3.21
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling foreign-types-shared v0.1.1
   Compiling futures-util v0.3.21
   Compiling fnv v1.0.7
   Compiling openssl v0.10.38
   Compiling hashbrown v0.11.2
   Compiling serde_derive v1.0.136
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling matches v0.1.9
   Compiling pin-utils v0.1.0
   Compiling futures-sink v0.3.21
   Compiling futures-channel v0.3.21
   Compiling once_cell v1.9.0
   Compiling futures-io v0.3.21
   Compiling tinyvec_macros v0.1.0
   Compiling httparse v1.6.0
   Compiling native-tls v0.2.8
   Compiling serde v1.0.136
   Compiling slab v0.4.5
   Compiling openssl-probe v0.1.5
   Compiling percent-encoding v2.1.0
   Compiling try-lock v0.2.3
   Compiling ryu v1.0.9
   Compiling encoding_rs v0.8.30
   Compiling httpdate v1.0.2
   Compiling tower-service v0.3.1
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.79
   Compiling unicode-bidi v0.3.7
   Compiling semver v1.0.5
   Compiling heck v0.4.0
   Compiling anyhow v1.0.54
   Compiling base64 v0.13.0
   Compiling strsim v0.10.0
   Compiling ipnet v2.3.1
   Compiling termcolor v1.1.2
   Compiling fastrand v1.7.0
   Compiling remove_dir_all v0.5.3
   Compiling textwrap v0.14.2
   Compiling mime v0.3.16
   Compiling indexmap v1.8.0
   Compiling proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
   Compiling proc-macro-error v1.0.4
   Compiling tracing-core v0.1.22
   Compiling foreign-types v0.3.2
   Compiling http v0.2.6
   Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.72
   Compiling tinyvec v1.5.1
   Compiling form_urlencoded v1.0.1
   Compiling tracing v0.1.31
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.72`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-installyyxHFg/release/build/openssl-sys-91e679f09e1fedf4/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  run pkg_config fail: "`\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"openssl\"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1\nerror: could not find system library 'openssl' required by the 'openssl-sys' crate\n\n--- stderr\nPackage openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'openssl' found\n"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '

  Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
  proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
  trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
  compilation process.

  Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
  For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.

  If you're in a situation where you think the directory *should* be found
  automatically, please open a bug at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl
  and include information about your system as well as this message.

  $HOST = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  $TARGET = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  openssl-sys = 0.9.72

  ', /home/kelvin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.72/build/find_normal.rs:180:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `avm v0.25.0 (https://github.com/project-serum/anchor#93332766)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installyyxHFg
```

I've also installed the recommended dependencies using the command below but still doesn't work.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config build-essential libudev-dev
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try installing `libssl-dev` also:

`sudo apt install libssl-dev`

Comment: Yeah, I've installed ```libssl-dev``` and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent help Federico Garcia - Kudos to you and thanks